# C++ headers and namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces

I got some confusion in mind between what my professor told us at uni and what I have read in Stroustrup's book.

- We all know that a C++ `header` is basically a collection of
  declarations (defined in a file.h) and they can contain for example a
  collection of classes. They are very useful because they give us a
  lot of features stored in a single space
- A namespace is someting invented to organize classes, functions,
  types (...) in a part of the program without defining a type.

I cannot see the concrete difference here when I have to create a project.

---

If I had (for example) to make a program that solves equations of various degrees, I'd put the classes that I need in a single file. For example I am going to place in `equations.h` all this stuff: class secondDeg, class thirdDeg, class fourthDeg and so on.

Why should I use a namespace then?

The answer (I guess) is: because you can give a name for a better organization (see std::cin). But in this case I should

1. Create equations.h (or whatever)
2. Create a namespace called `eq` for example
3. Put my classes in the namespace

Is this really necassary? Cannot I only use a header file and put all my classes inside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be conflating two distinct concepts. A header is a file, typically used to contain declarations. It can contain function declarations, classes, templates, etc.

A namespace is a means of defining a scope, within which all items declared are unique. This allows you to use function and class names that might otherwise clash with names in the standard. For example

```
namespace mystuff
{
    class list { };
};
```

Your list will not conflict with std::list.

Namespaces can and **should** be used in header files to declare the classes and such that are part of that namespace. However, as noted by others, using a 'using' directive in a header file is discouraged because it can create the very name conflicts the namespace was intended to solve.

Comment: This ispira exactly the answer that I needed, I really got the difference now. In your example you can call mystuff::list without having problems with the standard library. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

> Why should I use a namespace then?

A namespace can encompass multiple headers, eg., `namespace std` encompasses definitions from `<vector>` `<list>` etc.

You can define your own `namespace` to not pollute the global namespace and avoid conflicts. It's good practice to limit the namespace to the minimum for what you need, therefore `using namespace std;` is generally avoided.

Answer (score 6):

> Is this really necassary?

It depends. The better and more clear option would be to embed your declarations in a `namespace`.

> Cannot I only use a header file and put all my classes inside?

Sure you can, just avoid any clashes with symbols declared in the global (`::`) scope and refrain from `using namespace <xxx>;` in header files.

Comment: So a namespace is something like a java package?

Comment: @RaffaeleRossi Somehow, yes.

Comment: Ok very helpful, I guess I have figured it out. You suggest to not use namespaces in headers to avoid clashes with symbols in global scope?

Comment: @RaffaeleRossi Yes, never use `using namespace xx;` in header files, that may cause harm! Rather use namespace scopes explicitly, prefix `std::`, `eq::` as necessary. In translation units you may use `using` statements to pickup, but in header files that's a really bad idea, and error prone.